# HTML5 local storage caching url

Tags: javascript, html, caching, redirect, local-storage

I'm not to sure how to proceed with this. I want to use Local Storage to cache a URL once the user clicks on it. For example, I'm building a local content website. Once the user visits the URL **(www.example.com)** I have a map with markers on it that link to certain communities. Once the user clicks on there community it directs them to there local portal **(city.example.com)**. I want this url to cache in  the local storage so that next time the user visits the website **(www.example.com)** it redirects them to there local content website (city.example.com). Any help or advice on best practice for this we be really useful.

Comment: Why not just hand their browser a cookie?

Comment: I was going to use a cookie but I thought best practice might be to store it locally.

Comment: How do you define "best practice" in this specific case?  Why would LocalStorage be a better practice here?

Comment: From what I have read about local storage it seems more reliable and lease HTTP requests sent to the server. But I may be wrong.

Comment: [Read this first](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html), before you decide.

Comment: In a nutshell: With localStorage it becomes a per-browser persistent setting, sessionStorage is per tab only for the lifetime of that tab. Cookies can be associated with the user's session, and could thus be handled across browsers and computers if your users are logged in. And (not relevant to you, but for completeness) localStorage and sessionStorage can handle more data than cookies, because they are purely a client side solution.